# Displaying data from MySQL in HTML table

Tags: php

I came across an excellent tutorial here http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/display-data-array-mysql-html-table_t on how to output mysql into a table.

I searched for the article because I wanted to go from 1 column, to 3 columns. Everything works great, except for when I want to include a file in concatenation. I'm trying to do the following:

```
$html_table .= '<td>';
$html_table .= '' . include('data.php') . '';
$html_table .= '</td>';
```

However this doesn't work. For example if the data.php file contains some simple text such as test, I get the following on the screen:

test test test test test test test test test

1   1   1

1   1   1

1   1   1

The very strange thing is if I do a little test and instead type:

```
$html_table .= '<td>test</td>';
```

this works absolutely fine and the following is outputted:

test    test    test

test    test    test

test    test    test

I've looked for information about using include() within this context and I've found nothing. The reason I need to include a file is because the data I'm trying to output contain lots of text. Can anyone advise?

Comment: Include does not return the files contents, but `false` on error and `1` on success.

Comment: example 6 on the include manual page.

Comment: `$html_table .= include('data.php');` and `<?php return 'test';` in data.php.

Comment: @Dagon I was going to say `ob_start` and al.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead of `include` if all you want to do is get the contents of a file.

data.txt:

```
test
```

In your current file:

```
$html_table .= '' . file_get_contents('data.txt') . '';
```

Note that filename was changed to `data.txt` from `data.php` to avoid confusion, as it does not contain any PHP code.

If you actually meant to run some code in `data.php` to return a string, you will need to wrap it up in a function and `include` the file somewhere before you call that function:

data.php:

```
<?php
function getData() {
    return "test";
}
?>
```

In your current file:

```
include('data.php');

$html_table .= '<td>';
$html_table .= '' . getData() . '';
$html_table .= '</td>';
```

Of course you may want to remove the empty strings concatenation.

**Edit**

As you said in the comments the `data.php` contains a mixture of HTML and PHP, you may want to make use of output buffering to get the output of `data.php` when run.

data.php:

```
This is a mixture of <b>HTML</b> and <?php echo "PHP"; ?> code
```

In your current file:

```
function getIncludeOutput($file) {
    ob_start();
    include $file;
    return ob_get_clean();
}

$html_table .= '<td>';
$html_table .= getIncludeOutput('data.php');
$html_table .= '</td>';

echo $html_table;
```

Output:

```
<td>This is a mixture of <b>HTML</b> and PHP code</td>
```

Comment: i didn't make it clear that in the data.php file, I have a mixture of PHP and HTML, hence file_get_contents won't work. Your solution will work though, by having a function in the data.php file, just as long as I don't have to build the HTML into a string. Let me do some reading and see if this is possible. Thx.

Comment: Ok, for such a case I have added an example on how to use output buffering as another way of doing it.